# OSS Network Monitoring to extend

Tags: open-source, network-monitoring

My organization is looking at creating/extending a network monitoring solution (web based UI) for enterprise network monitoring.

We have a robust agent already that monitors a variety of custom metrics and can report this back via standard protocols (SNMP, webservice). We need to tie this into a overall network map now and I am leery of reinventing the wheel. Can anyone suggest a good open source network monitoring tool (enterprise level) that would be a good basis for an enterprise solution?

Thanks!

So far, I have identified 3 in the running:

- Zenoss
- Nagios
- OpenNMS

It seems like Zenoss covers most of what nagios does, but it begs the question, is there anything that Zenoss does that Nagios does not with freely available plugins?

OpenNMS is interesting to me because it can receive XML data via TCP -- and our software already sends a very detailed system description via TCP today so integration might be very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Coming back to this much later, our group decided on OpenNMS. We are glad we did!

The code is very maintainable and laid out very well, and the functionality is great.

It helps that it is 100% open source, too.

Drawbacks: The community is small and based around a mailing list instead of forums,etc